# Problem reading user ID to reply to message. Telegram bot with Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using **iogram** to create **Feedback Bot** on **Telegram**. When a bot receives messages, it forwards them to me, after which I reply to them with `bot.send_message (message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id, message.text)`. When the user has **permission** to forward messages in **the privacy settings**, then everything is fine, **but if not**, then the ability to reply to the message **disappears**. The question is: How can I reply to messages if the user has disabled permission to forward messages in the privacy settings?

Answer (score 0):

### Chain

`Customer -> Bot -> You -> Bot -> Customer`

### Customer + Bot

In `Customer -> Bot` and `Bot -> Customer` communications, participants can see each other.

Thus, even Customers restricts the forwardind of messages, bot can still answer, because it answers to direct (not forwarded) message.

### You + Bot

For `Bot -> You -> Bot` communication use simple (not forwarded) messages.

1. Just link Customer's message to some ID - `your_tracking_id`
2. Add ID to Bot's message, e.g.:

```
New issue: #id{your_tracking_id)
Oleg: 
    Hello World
```

3. When you reply to Bot's message it can get Customer's message credentials (`chat.id`, `message.id`) linked with `your_tracking_id`